# calling clearInterval() in setInterval not stopping the setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending an ajax GET request with javascript setInterval every 5 seconds. I want to stop ajax GET calls when the response status received as 'COMPLETED'. for I call the clear interval within if condition.
but it is not stopping the setInterval.

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {

  console.log('Trigger!!');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    enctype: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function(dataNew) {

      console.log('dataaa get' + JSON.stringify(dataNew));

      if (dataNew.jobStatus === 'COMPLETED') {
        $('#txtMessage').text('Upload complete.');

        clearInterval(intervalId);

      }

    },
    error: function(e) {
      $('#btnSubmit').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#txtMessage').text('Error Occured');

      clearInterval(intervalId);

    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });


}, 5000);
```

Comment: Do you get `$('#txtMessage').text('Upload complete.');` working?

Comment: Is there *any other code* - eg do you call this in a loop?

Comment: yes it is working @freedomn-m

Comment: @@freedomn-m  im not calling this within loop

Comment: Break it down bit by bit.  Remove the ajax call so you have very simple, eg https://jsfiddle.net/p6dmg0ea/1/ then add the ajax call back - add a `console.log(intervalId)` inside the setInterval *and also just* before clearInterval - are they the same value?  Does your ajax call take more than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax call like below:

```
var interval = setInterval(callAjaxFunc, 5000); 
function callAjaxFunc() {
 console.log('Trigger!!');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    enctype: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function(dataNew) {

      console.log('dataaa get' + JSON.stringify(dataNew));

      if (dataNew.jobStatus === 'COMPLETED') {
        $('#txtMessage').text('Upload complete.');

       clearInterval(interval);

      }

    },
    error: function(e) {
      $('#btnSubmit').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#txtMessage').text('Error Occured');

      clearInterval(interval);

    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    },
    complete: function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });

  
}
```